# UIDatePicker doesn't print out a date

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uidatepicker

I implemented a UIDatePicker into my app. If I change the default date after the date picker was popping up, the date picker gives a valid date back. But if I'd like to choose the current date (I don't have to change the date picker) the date picker doesn't give a date back. Does someone knows a solution for this in Swift?

```
    //Date Picker config.

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    dateLabel.text = strDate
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you showed some code illustrating the problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to put pieces of code that you tried, and show us where is exactly the problem

Comment: I added some code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a callback when you **change** the date (`valueChanged`). So it is normal you don't get it when you just dismiss the picker without changing the date.

You have to know the date before you present your date picker, in case you don't set it, or if you want to cancel your selection if you handle it.

---

Create a var *(I generally call it* `now` *)* where you store the currentDate (`NSDate()`) and set it to the `date` property of your `UIDatePicker`, so you know the date when the picker was presented since the default datePicker's date displayed is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you set UIDatePicker's date in code, it doesn't run valueChanged events. You have to extract the date string update into a separate method and update it directly.

Also, don't treat the UIDatePicker as the sole date value source. Keep the model separate.

i.e.

```
var date = NSDate()

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {
  self.date = datePicker.date
  self.updateDateStringWithDate(self.date)
}

func resetDate() {
  self.date = NSDate()
  self.datePicker.date = self.date
  self.updateDateStringWithDate(self.date)
}

func updateDateStringWithDate(date: NSDate) {
  var dateFormatter = UIDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

  var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
  dateLabel.text = strDate
}
```

Also as a side note, don't create a new UIDateFormatter every time it's needed, because its initialisation is relatively expensive.